# Getting item's index from id in ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I need to get item's index(position) knowing its ID while using ExpandableListView.
Is there any way to do this without making complete hash id->index and searching it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getPackedPositionForChild()
```

and

```
getFlatListPosition()
```

On the ExpandableListView are your friends